# Mirroring an external API and merging with other data as microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices

## Use Case

I'm planning a system that should provide the following functionality:

**Frontend**

You have categories: "Currently Popular", "Newcomers", "Classics". Each category should show a list of movies that fit the category title.

**Backend:**

The decision of which movie belongs into which category is mostly based on the ratio of viewership numbers and release date / age of the movie.

There are two external sources (Public APIs) from which I plan to gather my data from:

1. **Movies** - A source of truth about which films exist and metadata around the movie itself. Basically [IMDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMDb).
2. **Movie Viewership Numbers** - An external API that tells me how many people have viewed a Movie per day, per medium (cinema, netflix, etc.) and other statistics.

I need to map the statistics from Source 2 to the movies of source 1, so theres an inherent necessity of communication (and coupling?) between the two domains.

---

## How would this look like as a micro services oriented system?

**Solution A**

Should I have a single "game service" that saves the data from Source 1 into one table and the stats from Source 2 into another table and exposes the combined data from a single endpoint.

OR

**Solution B**

Should I have two different services for each and combine the data in my api gateway. In this case, how do I model the inherent dependency of having to map the statistics to my source-of-truth movie service/database?

---

## Thoughts

I understand that [`domain object = microservice` is not the way to go](https://www.tigerteam.dk/2014/micro-services-its-not-only-the-size-that-matters-its-also-how-you-use-them-part-2/), so the literature and community "tells" me to pick Solution A, but I intuitively prefer Solution B. What if I want to display movie trailers in the future and theres a third external API for those. Would I cram those in the single service or create a new one?

I don't have the experience and frankly a deep enough understanding of domain driven design or software architecture to come to a sensible conclusion here.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did the answer below helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a problem to be solved by an ETL tool: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load

I know that AWS provides an ETL service called "Glue": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/getting-started.html